How to rebuild door threshold when using self leveler to outside door
I am pouring self leveler before putting in new floors. I have to raise the floor 1 inch. How should I rebuild the threshold of the outside door?

I thought to just use self leveler all the way to the outside of the door then cut down the door.
I thought to build a small concrete threshold pad to the outside then pour the self leveler up to the new small concrete threshold pad, then cut down the door.
I thought of finding a raised threshold that was a perfect fit, then pouring the self leveler to the new threshold then cut down the door. I am not sure if there if something like this exists though.

Any thoughts would be helpful from experienced contractors.
Here are some pictures and video link (Starting at the outside door where I need to redo the door threshold and ending with the part of the house that I need to bring the floors to be level to)
My unlevel floors video




You'd sure help your case with some photos.  Also, why do you need to raise your floor a whole inch?  Is that because you have an area(s) that's raised by an inch compared to the rest of the floor?

Depending on the size of the room using self leveler to raise an inch can get very pricy. Some pics and an explanation of what your situation is may get you good advice that can save time and money.  Otherwise I'd say build a dam outside the door and pour the leveler...but that is not what I would do.

Thanks. Please see my picture and youtube video link.

By my calculation, you are raising the floor 1 1/2" at the door location. The door is being used to protect from the exterior elements. Will that still be its job? Regardless, taking that much off the door given the already slim dimension at the base is a mistake. The door is double glazed. You will be removing a lot of strength from the door.

I can get a new door. The door itself is not my issue. It is correctly doing the threshold without it deteriorating.

What is the final goal here?  I don't see a drop from one level of floor to another.  If it is to level the floor for new flooring it may not need to be such a great amount.  The floor in my condo slopes over 2 inches from the front of the unit to the back in a span of about 54 feet. However it is not noticed and caused no problems with the tile flooring because it is flat...just not level.

It's true the old laundry room is sloping because of settling I guess. The main goal is leveling the part where the old florida room meets the rest of of the house, which is only 3/8"
